# How to set my variable so D3 data update finds the right object property?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've got some radio buttons that interact with an SVG via D3...

```
<ul>
 <li><input type="radio" name="xyz" onclick="updateMap('someProp1')" />Some label</li>
 <li><input type="radio" name="xyz" onclick="updateMap('someProp2')" />Some label</li>
 <li><input type="radio" name="xyz" onclick="updateMap('someProp3')" />Some label</li>
 etc...
```

I've got data like so ...

```
var myData = {
{
  "title" : "Some Title",
  "desc" : "Some description",
  "states" : [    {
      "st" : "AK",
      "someProp1" : 0.067,
      "someProp2" : 0.01,
      "someProp3" : 0.468
    },
    {
      "st" : "MI",
      "someProp1" : 0.067,
      "someProp2" : 0.01,
      "someProp3" : 0.468
    },
etc...
}
```

Using D3, I bound myData to a bunch of SVG groups of paths (i.e. shapes of US states) and then, among other things, painted the groups as choropleths and built a corresponding map legend.

When someone clicks a radio button, I need to repaint the SVG groups, change the legend, and update a few other things. With simpler visualizations, I've just used a set of if/else statements to get the job done. Like so ...

```
function updateMap(whatSelection){
  theSVGshapes.attr({
   'height' : function(d){
     if (whatSelection === 'someProp1') { return h - yScale(d.someProp1); }
     else if (whatSelection === 'someProp2') { return h - yScale(d.someProp2); }
     etc....
```

But I have too many options for this brute force approach. I really need to seemlessly use the value passed by the firing of the function via the radio buttons. Something like ...

```
function updateMap(whatSelection){
  theSVGshapes.attr({
   'height' : function(d){ return d.whatSelection; }
   etc.....
```

This doesn't work, of course. Console tells me d is not defined. Among other problems, I'm really asking it to set the height to d.'someProp1'.

So, this is a very long way of asking something that I don't quite know how to articulate...which is probably why I can't find the answer elsewhere on StackExchange.

Namely (well, as best as I can name it): How do I set a variable to be equal to an object's property value so that I can use that variable in multiple repaint commands in D3?

Comment: Have you tried `d[whatSelection]`?

Comment: It works, thanks! Is there someway you can articulate what this means for me? That will help me on my "learning to JavaScript" journey. I really had no idea how to describe my issue here.

Comment: I'll add an answer with some more explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, there are two ways of accessing attribute values in objects. The first form is what you're using in your code:

```
d.attribute
```

This works fine if the name of the attribute is static. If it isn't, the second form is better:

```
d["attribute"]
```

It achieves exactly the same thing, except that you can pass any (dynamically-generated) string. So in your case you need to use

```
d[whatSelection]
```